# Changing an email address for users who are already in a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We use the force.com platform in combination with Marketing Cloud. We have journey's running with DE's which are updated by automations. Plus we have journeys running on Salesforce Data.

The problem is that our account managers update the email addresses of our users on regular base.

My question: How can i make sure that users who are already in a journey, and their email address has been changed by our account manager (or by themself via their profile), that this new email address is used from that point on instead of the old email address?

Problem is that journeys with a DE as entry event which is updated by an automation will use the old email address, because the data were the user enters the journey with will remain the same. Can we in a way update the email address of this user?

When entry event of a journey is Salesforce Data, the email address of the user isn't updated as well during the journey right?

All in all, how can i solve this problem?

Cheers,
Wouter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update an email address of a subscriber inside the journey. Just make sure your journey settings are set to your subscriber model instead of your dataextension. Than the journey will take the email address that is stored inside the subscriberlist/contact-model and not inside the dataextension.

[image]

When the actual send happens the journey builder will reference the subscriberkey of the dataextension (which relates to the subscriberkey of the subscriber table) and take that email address from the contact data.

Be aware that updates on email addresses should always be done on the central susbcriber data/contact-model if you want to send out emails with subscriberkeys that do not change (and are not the email address).

Comment: Hi Johannes, our contact model is based on the Salesforce object Contact. Which is a synchronized data extension from the force.com platform. So this should be fine then right?

Comment: If the platform is synchronized - i believe that is fine, but thats an answer i cannot give you. But my understanding would be: Yes it should be fine, else salesforce is doing something wrong with the synchronisation. I haven't configured synchronisation because we use marketing cloud stand alone.

Comment: You simply have to choose the email address from Contact_Salesforce population. Then you will be sure that Marketing Cloud will pico the latest email address synchronized from Salesforce Platform.

Comment: Yes, this will work. You should probably check your sync interval to have a good idea how current your data will be